# Removing extra whitespace between words using for loop Python

Tags: python

I need to remove all excess white space and leave one space, between my words while only using if and while statements. and then state the amount of characters that have been removed and the new sentence 
edit, it must also work for punctuation included within the sentence.
This is what I have come up with however it leaves me with only the first letter of the sentence i choose as both the number, and the final sentence. can anyone Help.

```
def cleanupstring(S):

    lasti = ""
    result = ""
    for i in S:
        if lasti == " " and i == " ":
            i = ""
        else:
            lasti = i    
        result += i    

    return result

sentence = input("Enter a string: ")

outputList = cleanupstring(sentence)

print("A total of", outputList[1], "characters have been removed from your string.")
print("The new string is:", outputList[0])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleaning up a string without split/strip/built-in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438554/cleaning-up-a-string-without-split-strip-built-in-functions)

Comment: One easy: `print("The new string is:", outputList)`.

Comment: You only print the first item if the string

Comment: Also outputList[1] is not the amount of characters that have been removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

```
def cleanupstring(S):
counter = 0
lasti = ""
result = ""
for i in S:
    if lasti == " " and i == " ":
        i = ""
        counter += 1
    else:
        lasti = i
        result += i
return result, counter

sentence = input("Enter a string: ")
outputList = cleanupstring(sentence)

print("A total of", outputList[1], "characters have been removed from your string.")
print("The new string is:", outputList[0])
```

The counter keeps track of how often you remove a character and your [0] and [1] work now the way you want them to.
This is because outputList is now a tuple, the first value at index 0 is now the result and the second value at index 1 is the counter.

Comment: thank you that works! I forgot to mention it also must work with sentences containing punctuation like commas and periods. a space after is okay. where can i build in that condition? thanks again

Comment: It doesn't remove any spaces behind a comma is just leaves the one before so 'hello , world' would not be changed.

Comment: this is because the first space between them is not considered "extra" when it is checking the string?

Comment: @Funnacho yes, the program doesn't check if the spaces are on the correct position it just removes one if there are 2 behind each other.

Comment: thanks for all the clarification and help, would you be able to send me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Comment: @Funnacho One way of doing this is by also keeping track of the next character in the sentence and check if it is a comma or a point. If this is the case i (space) is removed even if the lasti is not a 'space'. Feel free to accept my answer for reputation sake.

Comment: thanks again. i tried adding in a while statement that says if there is a space plus a specific punctuation mark replace it with just the punctuation mark. but it is not working. would you mind showing me what you would do in your program?